# Displaying images from azure blob container

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service

I have an asp mvc application where I am trying to display images that have been stored in Azure blob storage.

When I return the string the browser just shows as a broken image. When I right click and "inspect" and click the generated URI I recieve the following message

> `BlobNotFound`
>   
>   The specified blob does not exist. RequestId:f7c32876-0001-013e-539d-dede28000000 Time:2016-07-15T13:30:49.7560775Z

I have downloaded `Azure Storage Explorer` and can see the file. I have tried to change the access levels on the container to `read access for blobs only` from `no public access` (but I thought I did that in code with the line `PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob`).

How do I display images that are contained in storage?

```
public string Index()
    {
        CloudBlockBlob blob = GetBlobInContainer("blobContainerTjsContainer", "PS-ICON-120x120_140.jpg");
        return "<img src="+ blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri +" alt='PS Image'>";
    }

CloudBlockBlob GetBlobInContainer(string container, string fileName)
    {
        //use web.config appSetting to get connection setting .NET Framework's ConfigurationManager class can also be used for this
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
        //create the blob client
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        //retrieve a refernce to a container
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(container));
        //set permission to show to public
        blobContainer.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob});
        blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
        // Retrieve reference to a blob named "photo1.jpg".
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
        return blockBlob;
    }
```

**EDIT**

After further reading I have changed

```
// Retrieve reference to a blob named "photo1.jpg".
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
        return blockBlob;
```

to

```
// Retrieve reference to a blob named "photo1.jpg".
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
        blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpg";
        blockBlob.SetProperties();
        return blockBlob;
```

this changes returns an exception

> Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Do I need to do something different at the time of uploading?

**Edit**

@Gaurav Mantri

[image: azure storage]

I can see that it is stored as `application/octet-stream` but when I tried to change this to image/jpg using

```
blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpg";
    blockBlob.SetProperties();
```

I got a 404 exception at set properties. When I pull the image, while debugging I can see the image name is the same as it was when I uploaded it

at the time of uploading I used the below code

```
    void UploadFile(string filePath)
    {
        //use web.config appSetting to get connection setting .NET Framework's ConfigurationManager class can also be used for this
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
        //create the blob client
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        //retrieve a refernce to a container
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("blobContainerTjsContainer"));
        //create a container if it doesnt exist
        blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
        //gets the reference to the blob that will be written or OVER written
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("my-image-blob");

        using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you see a file named `PS-ICON-120x120_140.jpg` in your blob container? Can you share a screenshot of that from Azure Storage Explorer?

Comment: I have tried to add enough extra information, let me know if you need more

Comment: Thanks. So I noticed a few things: 1) In `UploadFile`, you're not setting the blob container's ACL as you're doing it in `GetBlobInContainer` function. Can you please check if the blob container's ACL is indeed `Blob` and not `Private`? 2) You're actually passing a different blob name to `GetBlobInContainer` function than what you're doing in `UploadFile`. Please make sure that both are the same.

Comment: Thanks to your first comment I gave a couple of things a try one was call blockBlob.Properties.ContentType but DON'T call blockBlob.SetProperties(); I didnt expect this to work because I thought blockBlob.SetProperties(); save the settings. It has worked, thankyou for you help. I will happly mark any any relevant answer you give as correct

Comment: I'm really not sure what exactly I did that helped you :P but I am glad to hear that you're unblocked. Please provide an answer yourself telling what you did. It is completely fine to answer one's own question and even accept it :).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to the comments from Gaurav I was able to work out my problem.

I was downloading the file as below

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpg";
blockBlob.SetProperties();
return blockBlob;
```

But when storing the file I was not setting the content type so it was being saved as `application/octet-stream` and the above code was trying to convert the type when calling the file. By setting the type prior to uploading I was able to simply call the file and have it displayed as an image e.g.

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("my-image-blob");
blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpg";

using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath))
{
    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
}
```